# View.getX and getY returns zero

Tags: android

I have two `ImageView`s. I want to move one to on top of the other.
When I try to retrieve the value of one of the `ImageView`s position to move the other to it I get 0 on both x and y.
I have tried using `getLeft`/`getTop`, `getX()`/`getY()`, and `getPositionOnScreen()`; They all return 0.   Both views are inside of the same constraint layout.

XML of `ImageView` returning 0:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/playerOneCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/card" />
```

Code to return position:

```java
int x = playerOneCardMove.getLeft();
int y = playerOneCardMove.getTop();
```

I have also used the following:

```java
int x = playerOneCardMove.getX();
int y = playerOneCardMove.getY();
```

and:

```java
int[] imageCoordinates = new int[2];
playerOneCard.getLocationOnScreen(imageCoordinates);
int x = imageCoordinates[0];
int y = imageCoordinates[1];
```

Code that executes `onClick` to move the card:

```java
public void transitionPlayerOne() {
    int x = playerOneCard.getLeft();
    int y = playerOneCard.getTop();
    TranslateAnimation animation =
            new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, x, Animation.ABSOLUTE, y);
    animation.setDuration(1000); // animation duration
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    playerOneCardMove.startAnimation(animation); // start animation
}
```

Comment: are you using this code in `onCreate` on some `click actions`?

Comment: That depends on when you try to obtain the position, at the onCreate method the layout is not finished inflating so positions will be 0

Comment: When you press a button it should move so on a click action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When are you trying to get the X and Y of the ImageViews? If you are doing it straight in `onCreate` (or some other place that the views are currently being laid), their x and y will be zero since they have not been laid out.

In this case, You have 2 options:

1. Use `View.post { }` and do what you are doing in the callback.
2. Use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` like below.

```java
imageview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // do something about the view's x and y.
        // also don't forget to remove this OnGlobalLayoutListener using
        // removeOnGlobalLayoutListener in here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I add this code into my onClickListener? I am not entirely sure how this works

Comment: just add the codes above (e.g. `imageview1.post(new Runnable..)` and inside the `Runnable`'s `run`, add your code.